# Flash file generator for php

Tags: php, flash

I have looked into this and found nothing that specifically answers my question.

Is it possible to create a swf with php. Here is the idea. You get a form where you can upload a bunch of images. With these images i want to create a flash file that has a link and the images must interchange every five seconds or so. Will this be possible and what do i require?

Comment: Yes its possible ..... see http://php.net/manual/en/book.swf.php

Comment: Ihsan, I have googled. I ask because the search was unsuccessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had good results with Ming, http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.ming.php. I guess you've looked in to html5/css3, it's not fully equiv to flash smoothness but it's closing up.

Edit:
the problem with ming it's you won't get it on shared host. You'll need a vps or similar.